# Windows 2003 and 2008 AD integrated DNS zones

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, active-directory

We have a Windows 2003 server DC1 which is our primary DC holding all FSMO roles.  It also is a DNS server for our domain domain.local which is an active directory integrated zone.
We also have a Windows 2008 DC name DC2 which is a DNS server with ad integrated zone for domain.local.  Both zones are set to "replication: All domain controllers in this domain (for windows 2000 compatibility)"

All servers have the correct DNS entries etc.  However in all dns servers dns event log there are event id 4515 indicating there are duplicate zones in separate directory partitions and only one will be used until the other is removed.

And I see these, there is a zone for domain.local under the default naming partition CN=System, CN=MicrosoftDNS, DC=domain.local.   As well as the DomainDNSZones partition DC=DomainDNSZones, DC=DOMAIN, DC=local, CN=MicrosoftDNS

It seems that the partition in the Default Naming partition is the one which is being used currently.  Which one should be in use?  How do I make the EventID 4515's go away? How could this have happened?

EventID 4515: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/867464

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the DomainDNSZone partition in ADSIEdit and inspect the attributes.  If there is a CNF or DEL in an attribute, it may require a bit of brain surgery.

Also, I would not leave the FSMO roles on Windows 2003 very long.  I've seen a lot of strange issues in that scenario, particularly if the domain has not been upgraded to Windows 2008, which occurs the first time that the PDC Emulator role is moved to a Windows 2008 domain controller.

More information on duplicate DNS Zones:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/acefekay/archive/2009/09/02/using-adsi-edit-to-resolve-conflicting-or-duplicate-ad-integrated-dns-zones.aspx

Comment: I am not seeing any funky attributes in the DomainDNSZone partition.  This partition looks to be old and no longer updated.  IE. it contains a lot less info than the MicrosoftDNS within the DefaultNamingContext which appears to be updated to current day.  I can go and delete this one, but I'm more curiuous why its there, and why Windows wouldnt delete it if some setting I choose told DNS to store somewhere else.

Comment: I'm not aware of many scenarios where AD would remove a partition automatically. I added a link for additional information on the duplicate zone issues and potential causes.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost: make sure you do have a backup before you change anything.

Does the zone in the partition that is currently in use have all the records it should have? If it does (and since you said both zones are configured for option 3), delete the zone in the other partition as described in the MSKB article.

After you fixed the issue (and provided you don't have any Windows 2000 DCs in your domain anymore) I'd suggest you raise the domain and forest functional level to "Server 2003" as that will gain you some [benefits](http://www.petri.co.il/understanding_function_levels_in_windows_2003_ad.htm). Also change zone replication to *DomainDNSZone* (all DNS servers in the domain).

Comment: It does have all the records I believe it should have.  The zone under the DomainDNsZones partition has a lot less info, and old info as well.  So I am assuming it is safe to delete.  I am more curious how this happened?